# Django styling a single option in a form select

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a simple form such as:

```
class ProjectInfoForm(forms.Form):
    module = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Module.objects.all().order_by('name'),
        initial=184
    )
    ...
```

in template:

```
<!-- module -->
<h2>Select A Module</h2>
<p>{{ form.module }}</p>
```

What I would like to do is style a single 'special' entry in the db (Module.name == 'Typical') with `<span>` tags. I have tried saving the object as Typical in the db, but `{{ form.module|safe }}` does not un-ecsape the html elements.

Is there perhaps a better way to do this?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not suppose to put any additional tags inside of an `<option>`.

I would recommend you use JavaScript to apply a class/id to this particular `<option>`.